# Bing Maps streetview not displaying only road map displays

Tags: bing-maps

I am new to bing maps api. I am trying to use streetside and when I use the coordinates from the developer documentation example, it works fine, but when I put in my own coordinates only a road map displays. Even if I select streetside from the map type menu I still have to click into a street to view it. How do I make the streetside api display the street view automatically from coordinates I input? This is from NYC so streetside must be available.

```
function loadMapScenario() {
    var streetview = new 

    Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('streetview'), {
            /* No need to set credentials if already passed in URL */
            mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.streetside,
            zoom: 18,
            streetsideOptions: { overviewMapMode: 
            Microsoft.Maps.OverviewMapMode.hidden, showExitButton: false, 
            showProblemReporting: false, showHeadingCompass: false },
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(40.716816225681576, 
            -74.00143212268763) });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the location you passed in is on a building and not on any road per se, which is why Streetside is not found and falling back to Road. There are two approaches you could try:

1. Specify a location that's directly on a street, say, (40.716676, -74.001002) which is close to yours. If you want the Streetside view to highlight a building by the road, try using `locationToLookAt` of `streetsideOptions`.
2. Pass in `panoramaLookupRadius` to `streetsideOptions`, which indicates the the radius in meters around your passed-in location to look for available Streetside view.